# Массив из случайных чисел

Tags: javascript, массивы

Всем привет! Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу
Есть массив из 8 чисел [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
Задача - создать новый массив из 48 элементов , в который будут добавляться числа из этого массива в случайном порядке, но чтобы каждое число встретилось ровно 6 раз

Comment: на русском языке сделать?

Comment: А зачем брать числа из массива если их можно генерировать напрямую? `floor(random() * 8) + 1`

Comment: Числа могут быть любыми. Это для примера

Comment: @ΝNL993 это не даст результата "каждое число ровно 6 раз".

Comment: В общем алгоритм: каждое число из списка продублировать 6 раз, итоговый список перемешать.

Comment: @user549234 если вы не совсем поняли, то вас просят указать язык программирования.

Comment: @insolor ой и вправду) Извиняюсь, не дочитал вопрос.

Comment: Вначале сформируй массив где будут указнные числа по 6 раз, а потом просто перемешай ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Язык Javascript. Может как-то сделать, чтобы подсчитывалось количество каждого эл-та на странице, и если =6, то его исключать , но как сделать не знаю

Answer (score 1):

`repeat` `n` раз повторяет массив `a`.

`shuffle` случайным образом перемешивает массив. [Алгоритм Фишера-Йейтса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0):

```js
const repeat = (n, a) => [].concat(...Array(n).fill(a));

const shuffle = a => {
    for (let i = 1; i < a.length; ++i) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));  // random in [0, i]
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];  // swap a[i] <-> a[j]
    }
};

const a = repeat(6, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
console.log(a.join(' '));
shuffle(a);
console.log(a.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
const repeat = 6

function getRandomArr(arr, repeatsAmount) {
  let newArr = []
  const initialArr = arr // Сохраняем оригинальный массив в новой переменной т.к. в последующем он (оригинальный массив) будет мутировать

  for (let i = 0; i < repeatsAmount; i++) {
    arr = initialArr.concat() // Используем concat, чтобы избежать мутаций

    for (let j = 0; j < initialArr.length; j++) {
      const currentIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length) // Случайный элемент массива
      const currentItem = arr[currentIndex] // Сохраняем число
      arr = arr.filter((_, i) => i !== currentIndex) // Убираем число уже сохранённое в переменной

      newArr.push(currentItem)
    }
  }

  return newArr
}

const newArr = getRandomArr(data, repeat)

// data = массив чисел из которого будет составляться новый массив
// repeat = мин. кол-во раз которое число должно повториться в массиве

document.write('Длина массива: ' + newArr.length)
document.write(' ')
document.write(newArr)
```

Comment: Получилось 42 элемента.

Comment: @Elmir поправил

Answer (score 0):

1. Создаём новый массив с нужной размерностью (количеством повторений);
2. Заполняем новый массив, используя в качестве значения исходный массив;
3. Преобразуем новый массив в одномерный (убираем вложенность);
4. Делаем примитивную сортировку.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

let fDuplicateArrayElems = (a, n) => new Array(n) // 1
  .fill(a) // 2
  .flat() // 3
  .sort(() => Math.random() - .5); // 4

console.log( fDuplicateArrayElems(arr, 6) );
```

Comment: Так нельзя делать сортировку. [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort): "Stable: The comparator returns the same result with the same pair of input."

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy: **абсолютно любая** машинная сортировка - псевдосортировка. В пункте 4 на этом сделан акцент.

Comment: Что такое псевдосортировка?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy:  Алгоритм Фишера-Йейтса

Answer (score -1):

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
let sixTimesArr = [...arr, ...arr, ...arr, ...arr, ...arr, ...arr];

function* shuffle(arr) {
  let newArr = [...arr];
  while(newArr.length) yield newArr.splice(Math.random() * newArr.length|0, 1)[0]
  
  return newArr;
}

document.write([...shuffle(sixTimesArr)])
```

Comment: Долго думал, не додумал, как можно подобное сделать без функции генератора? Нубоварик скажем

Comment: @Elmir смотрите мой ответ.